# Heroku TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I have the following problem. I keep getting this error message on Heroku when I update my dashboard page. I use the react-router in my App.tsx and my Dashboard Route is a Protected Route. I also have a login route. This will be called first if you don't have a jwt-token yet. After that you will be redirected to the Dashboard if the login was successful and if you already have the jwt-token then you will be redirected directly to the Dashboard. Below is the code.

**My problem:**
When I refresh the dashboard I get this error: Internal Server Error
With Heroku it looks like this:

```
 2020-09-21T15:23:42.881152+00:00 app[web.1]: [[32minfo[39m]: 2020-09-21T15:23:42.880Z: /dashboard
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886899+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886900+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.sendFile (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:425:11)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886901+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/build/index.js:50:9
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886901+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886902+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886902+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886902+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886903+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886903+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SendStream.error (/app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886905+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SendStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886905+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SendStream.error (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886905+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SendStream.onStatError (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
2020-09-21T15:23:42.886906+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:735:16)
```

**My Code:**

App.tsx

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

LoginPage.tsx:

```
const loginClick = () => {
   axios.post('/api/users/auth', {
       email: email,
       password: password
  }).then(res => {
       localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", res.data.token);
       history.push("/dashboard")
     })
 }

 <React.Fragment>
    {isAuthenticated() ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> :
       <div>
        <TextField
         variant="outlined"
         required
         label="Email Address"
         name="email"
         autoComplete="email"
         autoFocus
         onChange={handleEmailChange}
       />
       </div>
       <div>
       <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        required
        name="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        onChange={handlePasswordChange}
       />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <Button
          onClick={() => loginClick()}
          variant="contained"
          style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: COLORS.primary }}
        >
          Anmelden
        </Button>
      </div>
     }
   </React.Fragment >
```

index.ts (backend):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express, { Application, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import path from "path";
import tableData from "./api/tableData";
import tasks from "./api/tasks";
import companyName from "./api/companyNames";
import legalForm from "./api/legalForm";
import user from "./api/user"
import compression from "compression";
import logger from "./utils/logger";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import http from "http";
import https from "https"

const loggingMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  logger.info(`${new Date().toISOString()}: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  next();
};

dotenv.config();

const app: Application = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.PORT_DEV;

const url =
  process.env.MONGO_DB_MASTER ||
  process.env.MONGO_DB_STAGING ||
  process.env.MONGO_DB_LOCAL;

http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;

app.use(loggingMiddleware);

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 31557600 }));

app.set("query parser", "simple")

app.use(compression());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose
  .connect(`${url}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => logger.info("Database Connected Successfully"))
  .catch((err) => logger.error(`Database Connection Error ${err}`));

app.use("/api", [tableData, tasks, companyName, legalForm, user]);

app.use(express.static(path.join("client/build")));

app.get("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  //res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400')
  res.sendFile(path.join("client/build/index.html"));
  logger.info(__dirname);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

[filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtGQP.png)

Comment: Can you try `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));` instead. Not sure exactly where is your `client` directory so change that according to that.

Comment: I try it, I add a picture to my question that shows my filesystem

Comment: Does it still give you same error?

Comment: Well, not quite. Now it says "Not Found". Heroku Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/client/build/index.html'

Comment: NOt sure but check the path in error `/app/build/client/build/index.html` if the file exist or not. Just make changes in `res.sendFile` path according to the location of your `index.html`

Comment: Well, because back then exactly what you wrote did not work, I switched to it: res.sendFile(path.join("client/build/index.html")); Because he always gave me a wrong path

Comment: Does no one have an idea how to solve this? Does anyone know what is behind app/build at heroku?

Comment: *"path must be absolute"* - yours isn't; there's no point using `path.join` with a single value, and you're not actually *using* `__dirname` beyond logging it out. If you're trying to reference `./client/build/index.html` from `./build/index.js` you need to go *up* a level.

Comment: The problem is if I call it __dirname then heroku always gets this problem: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/client/build/index.html'

Comment: Right, because `./build/client` doesn't exist. You need to either: 1. change the output directory for the client build to that path so that it *does* exist; or 2. change the path so that it points to where the directory **actually is**.

Comment: Strangely enough, the problem has only occurred since I introduced the React router with the Protectedroute. Before that everything worked. I don't quite understand why he only gets this error when reloading the website. It works the first time it is called.